# Using AsyncLocalStorage in Node.js application

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose I have a simple application on Node.js and Express. I can't understand why AsyncLocalStorage (Example 1) may need if all the same I can get without it (Example 2). From the documentation it follows that ASyncLocalStorage works better with memory and is more optimized. Is this the reason for its use?

Example 1

```
const express = require('express');
const { AsyncLocalStorage } = require('async_hooks');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const asyncLocalStorage = new AsyncLocalStorage();

const requestIdMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  asyncLocalStorage.run(new Map(), () => {
    asyncLocalStorage.getStore().set('requestId', uuidv4());
    next();
  });
};

const app = express();

app.use(requestIdMiddleware);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const id = asyncLocalStorage.getStore().get('requestId');
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`[${id}] request received`);
  }, 0);
  res.send('Ok');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express server listening on port ${port}`));
```

Example 2

```
const express = require('express');
const {v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const store = new Map().set('requestId', uuidv4())
    const id = store.get('requestId');
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`[${id}] request received`);
    }, 0);
    res.send('Ok');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Express server listening on port ${port}`));
```

Comment: In your `app.get` call a function that does not explicitly get passed the store.  How does it get the request ID?

Comment: In your example 2, you're accessing `id` through [closure scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). If you had another file that was called from your `get` route then example 2 wouldn't work whereas example 1 would